# How to implement Python UDF in dbt

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Please I need some help with applying python UDF to run on my dbt models.
I successfully created a python function in snowflake (DWH) and ran it against a table. This seems to work as expected, but implementing this on dbt seems to be a struggle. Some advice/help/direction will make my day.

here is my python UDF created on snowflake

```
create or replace function "077"."Unity".sha3_512(str varchar)
returns varchar
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'hash'
as

$$
import hashlib
 
def hash(str):
    # create a sha3 hash object
    hash_sha3_512 = hashlib.new("sha3_512", str.encode())

    return hash_sha3_512.hexdigest()
$$
;
```

The objective is the create the python function in dbt and apply it to the model below

```
{{ config(materialized = 'view') }}

WITH SEC AS(
    SELECT 
         A."AccountID" AS AccountID,
         A."AccountName" AS AccountName , 
         A."Password" AS Passwords,
 apply function here (A."Password") As SHash
    FROM {{ ref('Green', 'Account') }} A
   )

----------------VIEW RECORD------------------------------ 

SELECT * 
FROM SEC
```

is there a way to do this please. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that UDF already exists in Snowflake:

```
{{ config(materialized = 'view') }}

WITH SEC AS(
    SELECT 
         A."AccountID" AS AccountID,
         A."AccountName" AS AccountName , 
         A."Password" AS Passwords,
         {{target.schema}}.sha3_512(A."Password") As SHash
    FROM {{ ref('Green', 'Account') }} A
   )
SELECT * 
FROM SEC;
```

---

The function could be created using [on-run-start](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/on-run-start-on-run-end):

```
on-run-start:
  - '{{ creating_udf()}}'
```

and macro:

```
{% macro creating_udf() %}

create function if not exists {{target.schema}}.sha3_512(str varchar)
returns varchar
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'hash'
as

$$
import hashlib
 
def hash(str):
    # create a sha3 hash object
    hash_sha3_512 = hashlib.new("sha3_512", str.encode())

    return hash_sha3_512.hexdigest()
$$
;

{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: please how do I reference the macro within my model

Comment: You do not need to reference the macro in your model. Macro creates the Python UDF (sha3_512) before dbt run is executed automatically via on-run-start in your dbt_project.yml. And after that, you just use the Python UDF in your SQL model.

Comment: @EdaJohnson I do not understand where you define the name sha3_512. Isn’t the handler called hash?